# How to interpet this train and validation loss curve

Tags: machine-learning

[image: loss vs epoch]

How do I interpret this?

Is it overfitting or is it a good fit?

I've used a 60-20-20 split for train, test and validation sets.

The test set doesn't do too bad, it gives an accuracy score of 0.75.

Comment: 0.75 accuracy is subjective. What is the performance in train and validation sets? You should give information about the problem, dataset, class distribution, loss etc.

Comment: It is an unbalanced dataset, and I use F1 weighted score as the metric.